# Print ranges of text starting from a line before match

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to print blocks of text that start one line before a pattern matches till the next blank line. I managed to do it with `awk`/`sed` but starting from the line that PATTERN2 (passed as variable `$ID`) appears and not the previous one. My inputfile:

```
2022/12/28 02:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN1
multiple lines follow

2023/01/14 04:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow

2023/02/15 08:07:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN3
multiple lines follow

2023/02/16 14:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow
```

....

with sed:

```
sed -n "/Processing id: $ID/,/^$/p" inputfile
```

with awk:

```
awk -v myid="$ID" '$0 ~ "Processing id: "myid,/^$/ {print}' inputfile
```

Desired output:

```
2023/01/14 04:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow

2023/02/16 14:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow
```

Comment: PlusOne for well formatted code and your showed tries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`, using `RS=""` to define blank-line separated records, and a conditional action with the `~` includes operator:

```
pattern="PATTERN2"
awk -v myid="$pattern" 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"} $0 ~ myid' inputfile
```

Output:

```
2023/01/14 04:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow

2023/02/16 14:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow
```

Comment: Thanks improving my answer

Comment: @GillesQuénot sorry, I know it's very similar. I wrote and tested it but there was a SO maintenance outage when I went to post and I didn't want to waste it after. I see it as alternative syntax aimed at helping new awk users learn the different approaches to similar problems, rather than as improvement. I've credited you now with a vote.

Comment: Despite the similarity with Gilles' solution, this was the fastest one.

Answer (score 2):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk -vid=PATTERN2 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"}{if ($0 ~ id) print $0, "\n"}' file
```

##### Output

```
2023/01/14 04:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow 

2023/02/16 14:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow
```

Answer (score 1):

##### With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) in *paragraph mode*:

```
$ perl -00 -sne 'print if /$id/' -- -id=PATTERN2 file
```

##### Output

```
2023/01/14 04:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow

2023/02/16 14:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow
```

Answer (score 1):

With extended `grep` matching:

```
myid="PATTERN2"
grep -A1 -B1 --group-separator='' "Processing id: $myid" file
```

---

```
2023/01/14 04:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow

2023/02/16 14:06:29 [Time]
Processing id: PATTERN2
multiple lines follow
```

Comment: The `-C` does both, yes?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Not quite correct I' m afraid, since it prints only one line after match, instead of "multiple lines that follow".

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution:

```
idline="Processing id: $id"
sed -e "/$idline/,/^$/!{h;d;}" -e "/$idline/{H;x;}" file
```